# Threaded application over OpenMPI only using 1 core on node

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmpi

I have an mutlithreaded application (not parallel) that I now want to execute on different nodes synchronised using OpenMPI.

When I run the application on the node I get 300 %CPU utilisation (top command). I assume this means that 3 processors are used 100% (4 Core node).

When I run the same process synchronised using OpenMPI I only get 100% CPU utilisation, which I assume means that all my threads are confined to only 1 CPU on the node.

Is there any way that I can get the program to make use of all CPUs on the nodes for the 1 task scheduled on the node?

I have looked at OMP_NUM_THREADS but that does not help, I guess that it is used when OpenMPI spawns its own threads to panellise work.

Comment: You should be able to spawn openMP threads within an MPI application without too much trouble. You mentioned trying OMP_NUM_THREADS but have you tried using `omp_set_num_threads(4)` within the code, it could be that the MPI environment messes up OMP_NUM_THREADS (just a guess).

Answer (score 3):

I found that the affinity of each process can be set using --cpus-per-proc and it did solve the problem.

BUT: --cpus-per-proc is deprecated (using 1.8.3) and I get the following message:

```
Command line options:
  Deprecated:  --cpus-per-proc, -cpus-per-proc, --cpus-per-rank, -cpus-per-rank
  Replacement: --map-by <obj>:PE=N, default <obj>=NUMA
```

I had to use the following to get the same functionality

```
--map-by socket:pe=4
```

Comment: Open MPI 1.8 introduced process binding by default. With previous versions binding had to be explicitly enabled. I'm expecting more and more questions like yours to start popping up on Stack Overflow as 1.8 becomes the mainstream OMPI version.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the use of -pernode flag turns off binding and allows each node to use its existing threads (in OPENMPI on OPENSUSE 15.2 ).
I, however, could not tell exactly how many threads each node used as I am sure my OPENMP command setting the number of threads to 30 was ignored and slots=32  and max_slots=32 dis not help.    I will next try your solution via --map-by.